# Trouble with lists and functions in python

Tags: python, list, function, turtle-graphics

I'm a student and one of my tasks involves drawing with turtle based on a randomly generated number. The following code is similar to the task.

```
def aaa():
numbers = []
for number_list in range(2):
    bbb = randint(1, 6)
    numbers.append(bbb)
```

My assumption was to create an `if/elif` chain to determine what action to take for each number generated as seen below. However, I'm having trouble as the `aaa` function isn't a `list`.

```
if aaa == 1:
print('a')

if aaa == 2:
print('b')

if aaa == 3:
print('c')

if aaa == 4:
print('d')

if aaa == 5:
print('e')

if aaa == 6:
print('f')
```

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Comment: btw, your `aaa` function can be reduced to: `def aaa(): return [randint(1,6) for _ in range(2)]`

Answer (score 1):

You must return a value from the function. after that you must loop through the list.

```
import random

def aaa_func():
    numbers = []
    for number_list in range(2):
        bbb = random.randint(1, 6)
        numbers.append(bbb)
    return numbers

aaa_list = aaa_func()

for aaa in aaa_list:

    if aaa == 1:
        print('a')

    if aaa == 2:
        print('b')

    if aaa == 3:
        print('c')

    if aaa == 4:
        print('d')

    if aaa == 5:
        print('e')

    if aaa == 6:
        print('f')
```

Answer (score 0):

aaa is a function, not a list. You need to call aaa, have it return the list and then iterate over the list.

```
def aaa():
    numbers = []
    for number_list in range(2):
        bbb = randint(1, 6)
        numbers.append(bbb)
    return numbers

numbers = aaa()

for number in numbers:
    if aaa == 1:
        print('a')

    elif aaa == 2:
        print('b')

    elif aaa == 3:
        print('c')

    elif aaa == 4:
        print('d')

    elif aaa == 5:
        print('e')

    elif aaa == 6:
        print('f')
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Your function needs indention so the interpreter will know which lines belong to the function.
2. You want to get a list with the numbers from the function, so return the list `numbers` from the function.
3. When calling the function, you need to add the brackets (otherwise you would just get the function object).
4. Instead of using several `if`'s, it is seen as best practice to use `elif` for all `if`'s fol
5. You need to iterate over all elements of the list you get as a return value from your function `aaa()`.

Your overall code should look something like this:

```py
def aaa():
    numbers = []
    for number_list in range(2):
        bbb = randint(1, 6)
        numbers.append(bbb)

    return numbers


for number in aaa():
    elif number == 1:
    print('a')

    elif number == 2:
    print('b')

    elif number == 3:
    print('c')

    elif number == 4:
    print('d')

    elif number == 5:
    print('e')

    elif number == 6:
    print('f')
```